# can't resize the qrcode img

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, qr-code

```
<style>
    #output {
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        min-height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

here is my css, when i try to generate the qrcode by using the qrcode.js.
then it show the QR code in the html element with the default size (200px):

```
<div id="output" class="text-center" title="S0009"></div>
```

really need help to resize the qrcode to 100px, pls help me , i tried many time with this:

```
<script>
    function generateBarCode() {
        alert('ok');
        var x = document.getElementById("output").title;
        $('#output').html('').qrcode(x);(or ({value:x,size:100}))
    };
    window.onload = generateBarCode;
</script>
```

But seem like it not work.

Comment: Are you getting any error on the console?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the properties of the #output element to see if the qrcode() function has overwritten any of your CSS properties?

Comment: @CarlosMartins: yes when i change the css to 100px the error show up :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at u.getLength (jquery.qrcode.min.js:1)
    at o.make (jquery.qrcode.min.js:3)
    at Number.<anonymous> (jquery.qrcode.min.js:26)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.r.fn.qrcode (jquery.qrcode.min.js:26)
    at generateBarCode (SearchBook.cshtml:466)

Comment: @rwp: tried many times and still not work :|

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    function generateBarCode() {
        var output = document.getElementById("output")

        var qrcode = new QRCode(output, {
            text: output.title,
            width: 100,
            height: 100
        });
    }
    window.onload = generateBarCode;
```

The documentation gives a pretty clear example on how to size the QR code. If [this](https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs) is the correct library. As a heads up, the QRCode object might not be available on window load. Maybe change to document load, or with Jquery `$(document).ready();`

Comment: i try this but the size still 200px i need to resize it to 100px qrcode:

    <script>
        function generateBarCode() {
            alert('ok');
            var name = document.querySelectorAll('.qrcode');
            for (i in name) {
                $(name[i]).html('').qrcode(name[i].title, {width: 100,height: 100});
            }
        };
        window.onload = generateBarCode;
    </script>

Comment: try the funtion $(document).ready(); but seem like nothing change.

Comment: @Skeleton1775 i've updated my answer. I forgot to set the width and height at 100 instead of two hundred. Where you have the width and height properties on the options object being passed through into `QRCode`, just set them to be the width and height, in pixels, to your desired width and height.